# Gradle test task: not found

Tags: testing, gradle, dependencies, task

apply plugin: 'base'

gradle tasks

```
Verification tasks
------------------
check - Runs all checks.
test - Runs the unit tests.
```

Configure test task

```
test {
    dependsOn bar
}
```

Error

```
Could not find method test() for arguments 
[build_740ewxgjzod99mmq37aj1jekp$_run_closure17@3e64d862] 
on root project 'foo' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
```

Comment: Are you sure `./gradlew tasks --all` or `gradle tasks --all` give you `test` task? It threw the error for me.

Comment: yes. it includes test task. I am using gradle 4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [Gradle doc](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/standard_plugins.html#sec:base_plugins), it said:

> Adds the standard lifecycle tasks and configures reasonable defaults
>   for the archive tasks:
>
> - adds build ConfigurationName tasks. Those tasks assemble the artifacts belonging to the specified configuration.
> - adds upload ConfigurationName tasks. Those tasks assemble and upload the artifacts belonging to the specified configuration.
> - configures reasonable default values for all archive tasks (e.g. tasks that inherit from AbstractArchiveTask).

As you can see, there is no test task, you can also verify in the [source code](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/v4.0.1/subprojects/plugins/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/plugins/BasePlugin.java#L70-L82):

```
public void apply(Project project) {
    project.getPluginManager().apply(LifecycleBasePlugin.class);

    BasePluginConvention convention = new BasePluginConvention(project);
    project.getConvention().getPlugins().put("base", convention);

    configureBuildConfigurationRule(project);
    configureUploadRules(project);
    configureUploadArchivesTask();
    configureArchiveDefaults(project, convention);
    configureConfigurations(project);
    configureAssemble((ProjectInternal) project);
}
```

So, the `test` task you are looking for is in either 'groovy' (groovy plugin includes java plugin) or 'java' plugin [Gradle doc](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_java_projects.html#sec:building_the_project):

```
> gradle build
:compileJava
:processResources
:classes
:jar
:assemble
:compileTestJava
:processTestResources
:testClasses
:test
:check
:build

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 1 secs
```

Let me know if this makes sense.

Comment: The test task is from a sub-project (java plugin applied), I believe.

Comment: @Sunnyday, then you should able to run like this `./gradlew :subProject:test`